# How to use FFplay Hstack with sound & subtitles on both Video's

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

Using a Batch file that plays 2 videos with Hstack using FFplay - I want to have subtitles on each video and have sound on 1 or the other or both simultaneous

I have 2 way using FFplay as shown today.  It really don't have both working but I'd be neat how to use both

this has subtitles on both videos but no sound [like want only Left Video or Right or both sounds

FFPLAY.EXE -f lavfi "movie=Left.mkv,scale=640:-1,subtitles=Left.SRT:force_style='Fontsize=18,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];movie=Right.mkv,scale=640:-1,subtitles=Right.SRT:force_style='Fontsize=18,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"

this has sound both videos but no Subtitles [like want only Left Video or Right or both sounds

FFmpeg.EXE -i "C:\Movies\Left.mkv" -i "C:\Movies\Right.mkv" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:-1,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=640:-1,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack=inputs=2[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]"  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -f mpegts   - | ""C:\AAvbprog\GameCord-VHS-v70\Extra Files\FFMPEG\FFmpeg.EXE" -i "C:\Movies\000KYCW-LD-08062017-0827(1).mkv" -i "C:\Movies\000KYCW-LD-08062017-0827.mkv" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:-1,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=640:-1,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack=inputs=2[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]"  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -f mpegts   - | "C:\Movies\FFPLAY.EXE"  -i -

thanx

Answer (score 0):

In your first command, add audio filtering.

`FFPLAY.EXE -f lavfi "movie=Left.mkv,scale=640:-1,subtitles=Left.SRT:force_style='Fontsize=18,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];movie=Right.mkv,scale=640:-1,subtitles=Right.SRT:force_style='Fontsize=18,PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][v1]hstack;[0:a][1:a]amix,aresample=och=2:ocl=stereo"`